# Using a list as input to a function

Tags: python, function

I have a function that translates subnet IPs into IP ranges, but I need to input a list of subnets to this function and I am having trouble doing it:

My function at the moment:

```
import ipaddress


cidr = ["187.11.62.93,187.11.62.95"]
def get_ip_range(cidr):
    net = ipaddress.ip_network(cidr)
    return net[0], net[-1]
```

I also need the output in JSON but at the moment that is not a worry for me.

```
return[net[0],net[-1] for net[0],net[-1] in cidr]
```

I should have 2 IPs here, the lower and the upper IP of the range, but I am failing.

Comment: Please add the expected output for that example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your list is global, so there is no need to pass it as parameter.
Also you did not put a comma nor quotation marks in your list (See below).
I am not entirely sure what you want to do, but your now you can pass the list :)

```
import ipaddress


cidr = ["187.11.62.93", "187.11.62.95"] # cidr[0] = 187.11.62.93 | cidr[1] = 187.11.62.95
def get_ip_range():
    net = ipaddress.ip_network(cidr[0])
    return net

print(get_ip_range())
```

Kindest regards